# Not able to Run test for Baseline profile using Gradle Managed Device

Tags: android, gradle, baseline-profile

I have created a benchmark module and within its build.gradle file I have added a managed device as following:

```
testOptions {
        managedDevices {
            devices {
                pixel2api30 (com.android.build.api.dsl.ManagedVirtualDevice) {
                    device = "Pixel 2"
                    apiLevel = 30
                    systemImageSource = "aosp"
                    require64Bit = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I run the command `gradle :benchmark:pixel2api30Setup` its working

But when I run the command `gradle :benchmark:pixel2api30BenchmarkAndroidTest`

It throws the following error:

```
Task 'pixel2api30BenchmarkAndroidTest' not found in project ':benchmark'.
```

Comment: Facing same issue. I can see the pixel2api30Check task in tasks list, however instrumentation command is not found within benchmark project. 
I am using AGP 7.2.2

Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of AGP are you using?

I was getting similar error but after upgrading AGP to 7.3.0-alpha07 from 7.2.2, I can now run the benchmark instrumentation task.

As stated in the release preview notes:

> Make sure your project is using AGP version 7.3.0-alpha07 or higher.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?hl=fr